# Wildfly - Allow connections to SSL sites without certs

Tags: java, ssl, wildfly

Is there a way for a web application to be configured (through web.xml) to allow connections to SSL sites withour certificates similar to `curl`'s `-k` option?

-k, --insecure      Allow connections to SSL sites without certs (H)

e.g. using curl we can do this:

```
# curl -vk --data "appip=adsfa123&login=testt@jelastic.com&password=adfas1123" https://app.sample-jelastic-server.com/1.0/users/authentication/cross/signin
```

My problem is that my web application is not able to access sites with HTTPS from within the container (or from server).

It is throwing this error:

> at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>   at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
>   at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)

With this, I think if we can configure the web.xml to allow connections to SSL site without certs then that should fix that.

Comment: What is the actual error? You only showed the call stack. The exception is on the line right above, and that's the most important part of a stacktrace.

Comment: Don't know which libraries you are using, so try web search for [`java ignore ssl errors`](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+ignore+ssl+errors&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Comment: @xybrek Your question title is misleading: SSL without certificates is not possible. Probably you want to ignore the certificates validation. It is explained well in the curl documentation: -k, --insecure

(TLS) By default, every SSL connection curl makes is verified to be secure. This option allows curl to proceed and operate even for server connections otherwise considered insecure.

The server connection is verified by making sure the server's certificate contains the right name and verifies successfully using the cert store.

Comment: If your application is having problems with certificate verifications (which is not visible from your partial stacktrace) when calling external services you have to do one of: 1) configure a certificate keystore and add it to the application when it is starting. The contents of the keystore should be the certificates of the service you are calling and their relative intermediate and root level certificates;2) override your client code that is making the SSL connections and tell it to not do certificate validations. The second is OK for testing/staging systems BUT NOT for production.

Comment: @xybrek maybe [this way](http://web.archive.org/web/20121022013056/http://exampledepot.com/egs/javax.net.ssl/TrustAll.html) covers your case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the following in the `standalone.conf` file.

`JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/<Path>/conf/xyz.keystore -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=password"`

In the `xyz.keystore`, add the certificates of the application you are trying to invoke. The system keystore is automatically added by the wildfly.

You can debug the ssl request and response you can add another configuration to the wildfly start up `-Djavax.net.debug=all` more on it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html)